# How to install X server

Tags: linux, xserve, java

I have a linux server where I want to run a jar file but when i run this its showing

```
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:432)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:403)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:368)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:158)
    at Imagecrop.CropImage.<init>(CropImage.java:21)
    at arrestcentral.ArrestData.<init>(ArrestData.java:34)
    at arrestcentral.ArrestpdfLink.<init>(ArrestpdfLink.java:28)
    at arrestcentral.ArrestpdfLink.main(ArrestpdfLink.java:110)
```

For this I would like to install

> X server

for graphical view.

Comment: Information like which distro would really help someone answer this question.

Comment: We really need to know what distro you're using. Linux is a kernel, not an Operating System.

Answer (score 1):

In a Debian based distro, you should run (as root or with sudo): `apt-get install xorg`. This will give you an X server. In a newer Fedora/CentOS/RedHat distro, run `yum groupinstall X\ Window\ System`.